# The issue of using Python to add custom attributes to the model in Blender

Tags: python, blenderkit

I want to add a custom attribute to each model, so I went through the selected models and added a custom attribute with the name "Cube" and the content as the model name to each model.

However, after executing the code, the program only added a custom attribute to the last model because I searched online for a long time but couldn't find any relevant content, And Blender's API related to custom attributes is a bit difficult for me as a Python beginner to understand, so I am asking a question here, hoping to get a recovery.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `bpy.context.object["Cube"]` change to `i["Cube"]`

Comment: `bpy.context.object` represents the active object, so it do with one object.

Comment: @XY Oh, thank you very much for the answer. I understand. I thought bpy.context.object was written according to API regulations

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate on what you mean by "API regulations" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More idiomatic IMO

```
import bpy

for i, obj in enumerate(bpy.context.selectable_objects):
    obj.name = f"Cube{i}"
```

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for an incremental integer variable.